# Auto remove or hide app's notification from Notification Area in Win10

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, notifications, notification-area

I have a winforms app works in the background with a `NotifyIcon1` to show some countdown balloon tips with the code below:

```
Private Sub tmrCountdown_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrCountdown.Tick
    If countdown > 60 Then
        countdown -= 1
    Else
        If countdown > 0 Then
            countdown -= 1
            ShowTrayNotification()
        Else
            NotificationForm.Show()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ShowTrayNotification()
    NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info
    NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "You have an appointment in "
    NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = countdown & " seconds ... "
End Sub
```

It runs well on `Windows 7` but on `Windows 10`, it causes the balloon to appear multiple times, and when the countdown is up, it leaves a bunch of messages in the `Notification Area` - which I have to remove them manually.

Could anyone give me a suggestion to:

- Remove or hide these messages from the `Notification Area` (because it has done its job).
- Let the balloon tips appear once when counting-down, not each time the timer ticks.

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you did something wrong. As you haven't told us what you did, that's as much as we can really say.

Comment: Hi @jmcilhinney, thanks for your suggestion, could you take a look again, I have added some coding.

Comment: The code you have specifically shows the balloon 60 times.  If you only want the balloon to be displayed once, write code to show it once.  If you're counting down then each number will only be the count once, so it should be obvious that you need to display the balloon when the count is equal to one specific number.

Comment: Is there any way to show a notification with the number changing (60..59..58...) each second?

Comment: It appears that Windows 10 won't display balloons like older versions and redirects them to its own Action Center notifications, so they play by different rules. I don't have the time or inclination to investigate those rules at the moment but you should.